# Are point to site VPN clients supposed to support peered VNETs?

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I have P2S SSTP connection to VNET1. VNET1 is peered to VNET2. VPN client does not add address space of VNET2 and hence routing from P2S client never works to VNET2. Are SSTP VPN clients supposed to be adding routes for all peered VNETs to installation file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the VPN clients will get routes to the direct-peered VNets in the VPN client downloaded file. In this case, you need to configure [Hub-spoke network topology in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json?WT.mc_id=docs-azuredevtips-micrum).

To allow gateway traffic to flow from spoke to hub, and connect to remote networks, you must:

- Configure the peering connection in the hub(have gateway subnet VNet1) to **allow gateway transit**.
- Configure the peering connection in each spoke(no gateway subnet VNet2) to **use remote gateways**.

You could get more information from the [step by step](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip182.html) to work with P2S VPN in a similar scenario.